# How can I programatically render Google Charts API images into a PDF file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I'm rendering charts on my website using the Google Charts API and I want to export these into a report for the users, most likely a PDF file. What methods are available to do this programmatically into a PDF file?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The solution given below is for Microsoft chart and the solution you were looking for Google chart. What I want know is that the solution given below fits the exact bill or you had to made some changes in your code? I have also same requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using iTextSharp. It's a free, open-source tool for programmatically generating PDFs from .NET applications.

I recently wrote an article on how to use iTextSharp to export charts generated by the Microsoft Chart Controls to a PDF: [Using Microsoft's Chart Controls In An ASP.NET Application: Exporting Charts](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134107/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100610-1.aspx).

Comment: Hi Scott, since you're apparently one of the four guys, you might want to weigh in [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420009/4751173).